# How to create a timestamp record and description on sheet 2 when macro button clicked

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have set out to create a worksheet that would enable easy tracking of coin taken in and given out.
I have been able to source a simple macro to create buttons, that will add the amounts I require.

```
Sub bPlus10bag()

Range("B2") = Range("B2") + 10

End Sub
```

I would like for everytime this macro button is clicked, sheet 2 would have a running list of the date and time the button was pressed and adjacent to this, the name of the macro pressed ie 'bPlus10bag' (revising names later).

I've searched through countless pages to find this but can only find part of what I need at best and I'm not proficient at writing my own code.

I am using Excel 2010.

Happy to give more detail if required.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Sub bPlus10bag()
Dim wslog As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wslog = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

'change the value in sheet 1
ws.Range("B2") = ws.Range("B2").Value + 10
' find the last row of column A in Sheet 2 and add 1 to get the
' row number of the next empty cell
lrow = wslog.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
' write the current date and time into the cell
wslog.Range("A" & lrow) = Now
' write the current macro name into the cell
wslog.Range("B" & lrow) = "bPlus10bag"

End Sub
```